# @angular/pwa not added to home screen

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have an **Angular PWA** app. in the browser add to home screen pops up and the browser confirms that the app is added to the home screen but when I check it's not installed.

In some cases, it installs but takes so much time.
Does anyone have any idea?

The problem is on mobile devices and all browsers on that platform.
I checked other mobile devices they are the same.

Comment: Which browser? Mobile or desktop? Have you asked someone else to try it on a new device to rule out that you may have something cached on your test device?

Comment: mobile devices. I checked other devices. It's not happening on my test device only.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Chrome Lighthouse confirms that PWA is ok and is installable